# Java Flight Recorder Docker Container

Tags: docker, java, containers

I want to profile a Java app inside a Docker container with JFR. How do I do so? The application I want to profile is not mine, so I can't alter the Dockerfile or any of the source code.

Docker run cmd:

```
docker run -itd --privileged --memory="_g" --cpuset-cpus x-y -p 
p1:p1 -p p2:p2 -p p3:p3 -p p4:p4 -p p5:p5 --net=host -v 
<hostDirectory>:<containerDirectory> --name=<containerName> <image>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Java app is running on a recent JDK, you may be able to attach to the process using jcmd and start a recording, i.e.

```
jcmd <pid> JFR.start name=test
jcmd <pid> JFR.dump name=test filename=recording.jfr
```

Comment: I tried this from both inside and outside the container and got the following error.
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:106)
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
        at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)
        at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.executeCommandForPid(JCmd.java:147)
        at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.main(JCmd.ja...

Comment: Then it's not running a recent JDK version.